# Get Attributes from XML using XSLT and parameters

Tags: xml, function, xslt

I did this xslt, it grabs a value from a XML, I have parameters that I can send to the for each to get what I need, it works with no problem, my for each do a comparison and if the value matches my parameter then it's done.

Does anybody knows if that is a good way to do it ? I'm telling that because I'm new to XSLT and that's the way I figured out that might work with no problem. I wonder if a function would be a better solution, in terms of coding and speed.

Cheers!

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="TransactionDataOfRequest">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="param1" select="'ADM_1'"/>
    <xsl:param name="param2" select="'ADM_2'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//x:form/x:add">
      <xsl:if test="@name=$param1">
        Question1=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="//x:form/x:add">
      <xsl:if test="@name=$param2">
        <xsl:variable name="test">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        Question2=<xsl:copy-of select="$test" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<transaction xmlns="TransactionDataOfRequest" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <success>true</success>
  <code>0</code>
  <value>
    <form>
      <add name="ADM_1" title="Question 1" type="String" isList="false">No</add>
      <add name="ADM_2" title="Question 2" type="String" isList="false">Yes</add>
    </form>
  </value>
</transaction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to print out all the questions and answers, you could do this generically with a simple apply template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="TransactionDataOfRequest">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//x:form/x:add"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:add">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit**

You can do this imperatively and and still DRY this up I guess:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="TransactionDataOfRequest">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="processQuestion">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ADM_1'"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="processQuestion">
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'ADM_2'"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="processQuestion">
        <xsl:param name="name"></xsl:param>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//x:form/x:add[@name=$name]" mode="process" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:add" mode="process">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>=<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi StuartLC, thanks for your reply, I need to manipulate the elements later, so I need to get them separately. That's why I'm using parameters.

Comment: I've updated with explicit calls to a call template (function). You can still avoid the `for-each`, the manual loop matching and the local variable.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that's the solution I've been looking for!